# error sending request for url (https://deno.land/std/encoding/csv.ts) (os error 10013)

Tags: javascript, deno

Unable to import the stdlib files from deno.land to local cache on running mod.ts.

*error: error sending request for url (https://deno.land/std/encoding/csv.ts): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: An attempt was made to access
a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (os error 10013)
Imported from "file:///C:/Current_Tasks/Deno/Kepler/mod.ts:3"*

Is there anything additional that needs to be enabled to import these files?

```
import { join } from "https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts";
import { BufReader } from "https://deno.land/std/io/bufio.ts";
import { parse } from "https://deno.land/std/encoding/csv.ts";

async function loadPlanetsData() {
  const path = join(".", "test.csv");
  const file = await Deno.open(path);

  const bufReader = new BufReader(file);

  const result = await parse(bufReader, {
    header: true,
    comment: "#",
  });

  Deno.close(file.rid);

  console.log(result);
}

await loadPlanetsData();
```

Update: Used
`deno run --allow-read mod.ts`

Comment: what happens if you open: https://deno.land/std/encoding/csv.ts in the browser?

Comment: It opens fine in the browser. i think its stopping deno program from accessing anything from internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { join } from "https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts";
import { BufReader } from "https://deno.land/std/io/bufio.ts";
import { parse } from "https://deno.land/std/encoding/csv.ts";

async function loadPlanetsData() {
    const path = join(".", "test.csv");
    const file = await Deno.open(path);

    const bufReader = new BufReader(file);

    const result = await parse(bufReader, {
        header: true,
        comment: "#",
    });

    Deno.close(file.rid);

    console.log(result);
}

await loadPlanetsData();
```

While running this file you need to give read access to the Deno.

**Deno is secure by default. Therefore, unless you specifically enable it, a deno module has no file, network, or environment access for example. Access to security sensitive areas or functions requires the use of permissions to be granted to a deno process on the command line.**

For the following example, mod.ts has been granted read-only access to the file system. It cannot write to it, or perform any other security sensitive functions.

> deno run --allow-read mod.ts

Comment: Nikhil, thanks for taking time. Yes i did use the following permissions while running the commands. And it returns the error above mentioned error

Comment: is there issue with internet connection/firewall ?

Comment: Seems like you have to use the --allow-net permission.
Please read the permissions list
https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/permissions